# Can the CKEditor Mathjax plugin be used to make inline math formula editing rather than in a separate window?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, mathjax, ckeditor5, mathquill

This web page shows CK Editor's mathjax integration

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/mathjax.html

But i need the math formulas to be editable inline in the editor field rather than in a separate window that opens.
Any ideas??

Not a developer so every effort so far is not worth showing